# New array of objects by comparing and pushing unique objects

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays of objects `exclude` and `people`, I want to create a new object by checking `exclude` properties against `people` properties and only adding objects in `people` that don't feature in `exclude`. So far my attempt is a little wild and wondering if someone can help make things a little better or offer a nicer solution?

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/kyllle/k02jw2j0/

**JS**

```
var exclude = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'John'
}];

var peopleArr = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'John'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'James'
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Simon'
}];

var myObj = [];
for (key in peopleArr) {
    for (k in exclude) {

        if (JSON.stringify(peopleArr[key]) != JSON.stringify(exclude[k])) {

            console.log(peopleArr[key]);
            myObj.push(peopleArr[key]);

        }
    }
}

console.log(myObj);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the assumption that `exclude` can have multiple items, I would use a combination of `filter()` and `forEach()` :

```
var newArray = peopleArr.filter(function(person) {
    include = true;
    exclude.forEach(function(exl) {
        if (JSON.stringify(exl) == JSON.stringify(person)) {
            include = false;
            return;
        }
    })
    if (include) return person;
})
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/6c24rte8/**

Answer (score 1):

You repeat some `JSON.stringify` calls.
You can convert your arrays to JSON once, and then reuse it. Also, you can replace your `push` by `Array.prototype.filter`.

```
var excludeJson = exclude.map(JSON.stringify);

peopleArr = peopleArr.filter(function(x) { 
    return excludeJson.indexOf(JSON.stringify(x)) === -1;
});
```

Here is the working snippet:

```js
var exclude = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'John'
}];

var peopleArr = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'John'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'James'
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Simon'
}];

var excludeJson = exclude.map(JSON.stringify);

peopleArr = peopleArr.filter(function(x) { 
  return excludeJson.indexOf(JSON.stringify(x)) === -1;
});

document.body.innerText = JSON.stringify(peopleArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`.findIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex)

```
var myObj = peopleArr.filter(function(person){
   var idx = exclude.findIndex(function(exc) { return person.id == exc.id && person.name == exc.name; });
   return idx == -1; // means current person not found in the exclude list
});
```

I have explicitly compared the actual properties back to the original, there is nothing particularly wrong with your original way of comparing the stringified version (`JSON.stringify(e) == JSON.stringify(x)` could be used in my example)